# C programe on Characters

Tags: c

/*Write a programme to check a password if it has an uppercase letter, a digit and a special symbol. (I have provided what I have done and I am not getting the output as required. Need explanation on where I messed it up.)*/

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int main()
{
  int i;
  int tuna;
  do 
  {
    printf("Enter a password:%c \n", tuna);
    scanf(" %c", &tuna);

  } while( tuna != (isupper(tuna), isalpha(tuna), isdigit(tuna)) );


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What''s the input? What output are you getting?

Comment: Your first mistake was attempting to use `scanf`.  You say you want to read a password, but the `" %c"` specifier indicates that you are only reading a single character.  Then you call `isupper` and `isalpha`, but you ignore the results of those calls (turn up your compiler warnings if the compiler didn't aler you to the fact that you are ignoring the results of those calls), and then you check if the value of tuna is equal to the call to isdigit...which will only be true if tuna is 0 or 1, either of which is highly unlikely if you expect a user to have typed values from a keyboard.

Comment: I don't know exactly what behavior you are expecting, but I can see several things that you will need to improve in your program:

Comment: 1) you need to make sure `tuna` is initialized before you print it
2) your loop only processes one character at a time. You should probably input a string at a time and then check the string character by character
3) the condition of the while is not a valid construct. It compiles, but does not do anything useful. Chaining conditions together is not done with commas but with boolean operators like && or ||.
4) change the type of tuna to char (to match %c)

Answer (score -1):

Here is a full solution for your question.

You needed to create a function which defines the special character.

Also, you needed to read the password as a string to then compare each character against your password rules.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

bool isspecial(char c)
{
    return ((c >= 0x21) && (c <= 0x2F)) ||
           ((c >= 0x3A) && (c <= 0x40)) ||
           ((c >= 0x5B) && (c <= 0x60)) ||
           ((c >= 0x7B) && (c <= 0x7E));
}

int main(void)
{
    bool contains_upper = false;
    bool contains_digit = false;
    bool contains_special = false;

    int i = 0;

    char tuna[65] = { 0x00 }; // password max length is 64 chars

    printf("Enter a password: ");
    fgets(tuna, 64, stdin);

    tuna[strlen(tuna) - 1] = 0x00;

    while (i < strlen(tuna))
    {
        if (isupper(tuna[i]))
        {
            contains_upper = true;
        }

        if (isdigit(tuna[i]))
        {
            contains_digit = true;
        }

        if (isspecial(tuna[i]))
        {
            contains_special = true;
        }

        i++;
    }

    if (contains_upper && contains_digit && contains_special)
    {
        printf("Password is ok\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Password is not ok\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use the `%s` conversion in `scanf` without a fieldwidth like this: `scanf("%64s", tuna)`. No need to teach newbies how to write unsafe software. And remember that `%s` won't  read whitespace, so your password can't contain spaces. To read passwords it may be better to use `fgets(tuna, 65, stdin)`. (Just don't forget to remove newline character, if any).

Comment: @HAL9000 thanks for the pointing out these small details, I'll update that in the morning

Comment: Why down voting?

Answer (score -2):

https://onlinegdb.com/rkuWbGhx4

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define PASSLENGTH 32

char *readpass(void)
{
    int c;

    static char password[PASSLENGTH];
    size_t len = 0;

    while((c = getch()) != '\n')
    {
        if(c < 32 || c > 127)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            if(len == PASSLENGTH -1) continue;
            password[len++] = c;
            printf("*");
        }
    }
    password[len] = 0;
    return password;
}

int isspecial(int c)
{
    return !!strchr("*&^%$#()@!", c);
}

int checkpass(const char *pass)
{
    int digits = 0, upper = 0, special = 0;; 
    while(*pass)
    {
        digits |= isdigit(*pass);
        upper |= isupper(*pass);
        special |= isspecial(*pass);
        pass++;
    }
    return digits && upper && special;
}

int main()
{
    char *password;
    int result;

    do
    {
        password = readpass();
        result = checkpass(password);

        if(!result) printf("\nWrong password\n");
    }while(!result);

    printf("\nYour password is: %s\n", password);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain the programmed?

Comment: Any comment DVers